# Add stream subtitle in html5 video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try add subttitle in video html5 with videosub.js

```
http://www.storiesinflight.com/js_videosub/
```

It work with file in same folder but not work with url stream !

```html
Subttitle not word with this code
<video id="my_video" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="" >

                        <source src="https://xmovies8.org/get_video?token=Xe-QdFvRw5e-6BEHzLTDguxNlJ5CW-mqdGyvtmNZ4GBGWVuHFrzPSoDtYJcG2z8XeIMOJ3GB7m7mz0m7-kVD6Abo5WJhrTsgUXlS2kQhRs-2-NCc9lzsPT6iNiKElzmAvPs5tlC6CQHrL9GgtTVSZ-46OELzd6rfI5pCbQOoZzEC6DTMSXpToY3MFAOzIsqadILaa3SYAwFSmjzirfTWtRXVcum7dpwbfY-IB6eV7oBzffJKJXUqeNi77NIejTky1IAH1bA3eByjWmE8ob4Odsfz8Otmkp4cAT1K9CVv-XgKVCZkMruxVO5-3ZoGQQ2hS8jDK-cdXCre4Vtux-JC9ymHxHCzue_95gPGdZTvPusUYCFUEngdfQZqssU82vK_8SdjgASmKx1EhUpgOrXMgLHidi1YC0hfZU58MZssFLt8l_pRkQAJU40pBJZYPtY_ii58sA5tDsDTS_inspRH7A" type="video/mp4" />

                        <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="http://phim.dinhvanvu.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Demo.srt" default></track>
                    </video>
```

But it work with

```html
                        <video id="my_video" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay="" >

                            <source src="https://xmovies8.org/get_video?token=Xe-QdFvRw5e-6BEHzLTDguxNlJ5CW-mqdGyvtmNZ4GBGWVuHFrzPSoDtYJcG2z8XeIMOJ3GB7m7mz0m7-kVD6Abo5WJhrTsgUXlS2kQhRs-2-NCc9lzsPT6iNiKElzmAvPs5tlC6CQHrL9GgtTVSZ-46OELzd6rfI5pCbQOoZzEC6DTMSXpToY3MFAOzIsqadILaa3SYAwFSmjzirfTWtRXVcum7dpwbfY-IB6eV7oBzffJKJXUqeNi77NIejTky1IAH1bA3eByjWmE8ob4Odsfz8Otmkp4cAT1K9CVv-XgKVCZkMruxVO5-3ZoGQQ2hS8jDK-cdXCre4Vtux-JC9ymHxHCzue_95gPGdZTvPusUYCFUEngdfQZqssU82vK_8SdjgASmKx1EhUpgOrXMgLHidi1YC0hfZU58MZssFLt8l_pRkQAJU40pBJZYPtY_ii58sA5tDsDTS_inspRH7A" type="video/mp4" />

                            <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" src="sub/je2.srt" default></track>
                            
                        </video>
```

Comment: Any cross-domain error showing up in the console? Check the network too see if anything is blocked there.

Comment: did you remember to include the javascript file e.g. <script src="http://www.storiesinflight.com/js_videosub/includes/videosub-0.9.9.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

```
<video id="my_video" height="100%" width="100%" crossorigin="anonymous"></video>
```

This is because CORS limitation.

Use **crossorigin="anonymous"** in video tag.

if the above code didn't work, then there is no way to load the subtitle from that server.

Hope it will works for you. :)